# Select a different Load Balancer for kubernetes cluster in OVHcloud

Tags: ovh

I am creating a new Kubernetes cluster on OVHcloud. I have 2 Load Balancers. My question is this how can I configure Kubernetes cluster in OVHcloud to use a specific Load Balancer. Actually, I am deploying 2 independent instances of the same application for 2 different organizations. That's why, I want to create 2 different Kubernetes clusters on the OVHcloud with 2 different load balancers. Can anyone guide me how can I configure a different Load Balancer for each cluster.

Answer (score 0):

My misunderstanding, by default a separate load balancer is created for each Kubernetes cluster on OVHcloud.